# CS Cart Enable Reviews and Comments to all products at once

Tags: php, cs-cart

I want to enable reviews and comments to all products at once. I found this link

http://kb.cs-cart.com/enable-reviews

But it I have to repeat the process to many times because I have a lot of products. It will take a lot of time.

I searched a little more and I found this post

http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/24672-enable-reviews-and-comments-by-default/

The problem is that the post is too old and the table is not that one or the data doesn't correspond.

I don't find a solution. Is there any way ... from phpMyAdmin preferably.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you run bellow query then reviews and comments will be enabled for all products.

Query:

INSERT INTO cscart_discussion(object_id, object_type, type) (SELECT product_id, 'P', 'B' FROM cscart_products where product_id NOT IN(select object_id from cscart_discussion where object_type ='P'));
UPDATE `cscart_discussion` SET `type`= 'B' WHERE `object_type` = 'P'

Answer (score 0):

If you want, i can use add-ons Alt-team: Enable All Reviews. It works perfectly!